# Unity2D: MissingComponentException: There is no 'Animation' attached to the "Arm" game object

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine

I am trying to make an animation occur every time the space bar is pressed using this code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ArmSwipe : MonoBehaviour {

    Animation me;

    void Start (){
        me=GetComponent<Animation>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)){
            me.Play();
        }
    }
}
```

Every time I run it i get this error

> MissingComponentException: There is no 'Animation' attached to the "Arm" game object, but a     script is trying to access it.
>   You probably need to add a Animation to the game object "Arm". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it.

```
UnityEngine.Animation.Play (PlayMode mode)
UnityEngine.Animation.Play ()
ArmSwipe.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/ArmSwipe.cs:18)
```

EDIT:

[image: Screenshot1]
[image: Animator]

Answer (score 0):

Your GameObject Arm needs to have an Animation attached to it.  It appears that you don't have such an Animation attached to the Arm.  Can you attach a screenshot of your scene graph, and your Arm object's inspector properties?

Also, you probably should use `Input.GetKeyUp` instead of KeyDown like you currently have.  KeyDown will simply cause the animation to re-play on each update, and it will look like it's frozen or stuttering.

Comment: I added images that I thought would be helpful

Comment: looks like your getting mixed up between the mecanim animation approach (Animator Controller, state machine to handle the animation based on triggers/values set within scripts) and the legacy animation approach (script calling animations directly). You might want to revisit the learn section on the Unity website and go over the mecanim tutorials.